# what is the wrong of the javascript code for the combobox?

Tags: javascript, jcombobox

I am creating a Dropbox to create charts. I have been using the function `change()` to get the text value from the combo box. This is the code:

```js
  
  //Load the Visualization API and the chart package.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  //google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart','table']});

  //get the selected value
  function change() {
   var listbox = document.getElementById("chart");
   var selIndex = listbox.seletedIndex;
   var selValue = listbox.options[selIndex].value;
   var selText = listbox.options[selIndex].text;
   
   //console.log(selValue);
  

  //chart for apply job post
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(dashboardDraw);

  function dashboardDraw(x, y){

   //get the location data from table
   var jsonLocationData = $.ajax({
     url: "post_location.php",
     data: '{}',
     dataType: "json",
     async: false
     }).responseText;

   //create our data table out of json data loaded from server
   var LocationData = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonLocationData);

   //get the company data from table
   var jsonCompanyData = $.ajax({
     url: "post_company.php",
     data: '{}',
     dataType: "json",
     async: false
     }).responseText;

   //create our data table out of json data loaded from server
   var CompanyData = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonCompanyData);
   
   
   //company chart details
    var optionsLocation = {
          title: 'Job Posts by Location',
         pieSliceText: 'label',
         tooltip: {isHtml: true},
         width: 700,
         height: 500,
         chartArea: { left:"5%",top:"5%",width:"90%",height:"90%" }
        };
   

        //company chart details
         var optionsCompany = {
          title: 'Job Posts by Company',
         pieSliceText: 'label',
         tooltip: {isHtml: true},
         width: 700,
         height: 500,
         chartArea: { left:"5%",top:"5%",width:"90%",height:"90%" }
        };
   
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
         if (selValue == 'location_val') {
           x = LocationData;
           y = optionsLocation;
         }
     
         if (selValue == 'company_val') {
           x = CompanyData;
           y = optionsCompany;
         }
     
       chart.draw(x, y);
     }
      
      

       
 }
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


  


<table>
  <th>
      <select id="chart" name="select1" onchange="change()">
       <option selected disabled="select">Select</option>
      <option value="company_val">By Company</option>
       <option value="location_val">By Location</option>
       </select>
    </th>
</table>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

The console shows the following error:

> TypeError: listbox.options[selIndex] is undefined[Learn More] 
>   dashboard.php:25:8

The problem part of the code is this:

```
var selValue = listbox.options[selIndex].value;
    var selText = listbox.options[selIndex].text;
```

How can I solve this problem? I have checked the code and there is no syntax problem.

Comment: Have you checked what value `selIndex` actually contains …?

Comment: the value is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using your debugger yet?

If you use the debugging tools built into the browser and set a break point just before the line the error occurs on you will see that `selIndex` is undefined. So you would then look at the line that assigns that a value.

```
var selIndex = listbox.seletedIndex;
```

You error is in that line, using your debugger you can see the properties available in listbox including `selectedIndex` note the `c`.

Comment: im using mozila debugger console and it shows the above error

Comment: he mean change `seletedIndex` to `selectedIndex`

Comment: owh..thank you..it solve the problem. sometimes when checking our own code, usually the problem cannot be seen although it is a clear wrong typed code.

Comment: thank you for David Waters solution and ewwink clarification

Comment: hey @jun if this solved your issue could you please accept this answer.

Comment: ok @David Waters, just accept your answer. sorry, before this, i do not find the accept link.